# Nesting React Native Content Messes With Layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, layout, flexbox

I'm building a react native app, and I had to make a custom button component.

When I was prototyping my interface, all of my buttons were just `<View>`. When I was finished making my new component, I just replaced those `<View>` tags with the name of my component `<SOCButton>`. After doing so, the layout of the content inside the button is completely messed up.

This is how it looked using the `<View>` component:
[image: How it's supposed to look]

Here's how it looks with my custom component:
[image]

Here's the code for my component:

```
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={this.depressed.bind(this)} onPressOut={this.unpressed.bind(this)}>
      <Animated.View style={[pressedStyle,{flex:1}]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Here's where it's used:

```
            <View style={styles.RecentPOV}>
              <View style={styles.RecentPOVProfilePicContainer}>
                <Image style={styles.RecentPOVProfilePic} source={{uri:'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/824476541384097793/qGw1Whej.jpg'}}/>
                <Text style={styles.RecentPOVUserRating}>4.0</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.RecentPOVInfoContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.RecentPOVUser}>Jack Kalina</Text>
                <View style={styles.RecentPOVStars}>
                    <View style={styles.FullStarsContainer}>
                      <Image style={styles.FullStars} source={StarShape.Full}/>
                      <View style={StarMaskStyle.RecentPOVStarMask}></View>
                    </View>
                    <Image style={styles.EmptyStars} source={StarShape.Empty}/>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.RecentPOVTimestamp}>February 2nd, 12:14 PM</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
```

And the relevant styling:

```
RecentPOV: {
backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
width: '100%',
height: null,
marginVertical: 15,
borderRadius: 20,
padding: 15,
flexDirection:'row'
},
RecentPOVProfilePic: {
height: 100,
width: 100,
borderRadius: 10
},
RecentPOVProfilePicContainer: {
alignItems: 'flex-end'
},
RecentPOVInfoContainer: {
marginLeft: 20
},
RecentPOVUserRating: {
position:'absolute',
fontSize:30,
fontWeight: '900',
color: 'white',
top:62,
right:4,
textAlign:'right',
flex: 1
},
RecentPOVStars: {
flex: 1,
top: -33,
width: '110%'
},
RecentPOVUser: {
flex: 1,
color: '#2b2b2b',
fontSize: 20,
fontWeight: 'bold'
},
RecentPOVTimestamp: {
flex: 1,
top: 15,
color: '#636363',
fontSize:15
}
```

Comment: `style={[pressedStyle,{flex:1}]}` Could this be the rootcause?

Comment: No, that just controls the scale when the button is pressed